# How to merge local commits after using bfg

Tags: git, github

```
local : a - b - c - d - e
remote : a` - b` - c`
```

Both a, b, c is different with each others because remote is cleaned by bfg.

In my local, two version exist.
original and cleaned by bfg version.

The problem is I already have two commits after remote head.

So I should connect local commit d, e ( not cleaned by bfg ) to remote commit a, b, c ( cleaned by bfg ).

**So i wanna connect local commit d, e to remote bfg cleaned version's c**

But i can't find how to do this......

Comment: What you should do is move d and e on top of the new branch. so: `git checkout the-remote/the-branch; git cherry-pick local-branch~2..local-branch; git push the-remote HEAD:the-branch`. Adjust the name of the branches and the remote.

Comment: To indicate that the remote's `a` differs from the local `a`, use a different name, such as `a'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another approach, a long one, but interesting for learning.

1- Make shure you are in the local branch you want to update

```
git checkout local-branch
```

2- Reset your branch to commit 'c' without loosing the changes from commits 'd' and 'e'

```
git reset --mixed HEAD~2
```

3- Stash (save) uncommited changes (from older 'd' and 'e')

```
git stash
```

4- Update local branch to match remote one

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/remote-branch
git pull origin local-branch
```

5- Recover the changes from 'd' and 'e'

```
git stash pop
```

6- Commit the changes

```
git add <files with changes from commit>
git commit
```

7- Upload changes to remote

```
git push
```